# MySQL Creating Tables from ER Diagram

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I am working on creating a database from an ER diagram however I don't think some of my primary and foreign keys are correct. The tables that I don't think they are correct in is the primary key in section and the FK and PK in enrolled table. I also don't think I am properly enforcing my FK constraints so that I can detect referential integrity violations.

Here is the ER Diagram I am basing my database off of.

[image: ER Diagram]

Here are the tables that I have made

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    StudentId INTEGER,
    FName VARCHAR(20),
    LName VARCHAR(20),
    DOB CHAR(10),
    Major VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(StudentId)
);

CREATE TABLE Phone
(
    sID INTEGER,
    Pnumber CHAR(20),
    Type CHAR(3),
    PRIMARY KEY(Pnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Class
(
    ClassId VARCHAR(6),
    Description VARCHAR(30),
    NumCredits Integer,
    Prereq VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(ClassId)
);

CREATE TABLE Section
(
    ClassId VARCHAR(6),
    SecNo CHAR(10),
    Semester CHAR(4),
    ClassRoom VARCHAR(6),
    TimeOffered VARCHAR(18),
    PRIMARY KEY(SecNo),
    FOREIGN KEY(ClassId) REFERENCES Class(ClassId)  
);

CREATE TABLE Enrolled
(
    StudentId INTEGER,
    SecNum VARCHAR(40),
    ClassId VARCHAR(8),
    Semes VARCHAR(6),
    GorDD VARCHAR(30)
    FOREIGN KEY(ClassId) REFERENCES Section(ClassId),
    FOREIGN KEY(StudentId) REFERENCES Student(StudentId)
);

CREATE TABLE Professor
(
    EmpId INTEGER,
    FName VARCHAR(10),
    LName VARCHAR(10),
    Dept VARCHAR(2),
    QualClass VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (EmpId)
);

CREATE TABLE Teaches
(
    Class VARCHAR(5),
    Section INTEGER,
    Semester CHAR(4),
    EmpId INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (EmpId) REFERENCES Professor(EmpId)
);

CREATE TABLE Qualified
(
    EmpId INTEGER,
    ClassId VARCHAR(5)
);
```

Thank you for the help in understanding how to create a DB from an ER diagram.

Answer (score 1):

You really should have a simple, standardized, `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` for every table. That makes referring to specific records a lot easier. It's also better to refer to tables by their primary key *only* when building relationships. String primary keys can be trouble, especially if those strings can change.

Additionally, your arbitrary limitations on string lengths is **extremely** annoying. Who are you to say people should only have names twenty characters long, or professors can have names only ten long? That's really sloppy. Unless you've got a very good reason, leave it wide open for these sorts of free-form fields, default `VARCHAR(255)`. Hard drives are measured in terabytes today and you'd need to have a hundred million students to fill up your drive with name data.

Otherwise, as a database this is okay. I'd probably discard this schema entirely and rebuild from your entity diagram, a great tool to have by the way, using the conventions of whatever development framework I was using. For example, Ruby on Rails, Django, Drupal, and Tapestry will all have their own ideas on how to name tables.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look, it looks to me like you would want to have a compound primary key for Section made up of ClassId, SecNo, and Semester assuming those three attributes make up the uniqueness scope for the entity of Section. You could also just have a SectionID that is unique (such as an auto-incrementing int)

For Enrolled, I would make an auto-incremented primary key and have a foreign key that links to the Section table depending on how you solve that entity/table's uniqueness.

Hope this helps. Of course, there are many ways to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually more useful and more practical to use primary keys specific to the database domain because in real life most entities don't have truly unchanging and unique keys perfectly suited for primary keys.

For example, data entry errors may necessitate the change of a student ID in the database. If you use a property that ends up changing then you'll have to create (effectively) a new student for every change in primary key(StudentId).

The alternative solutions:

- Use an automatic key in the database and make the StudentId unique but not primary.
- Use a StudentId as the primary key and have it be auto updated every
  time it changes in the parent table.

I don't recommend the second option because it is just a workaround the old problem.